# Should we turn off the HNQ feed on our main chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, hot-network-questions

Chat activity is pretty low these days. Because of this, the majority of the posts seen in our main chat room are from the HNQ bot. One user pointed out that [ignoring that bot makes the chat look much nicer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65018715#65018715). I think it’s time we turn the bot off for everyone, at least for now. While activity is low, this would allow for some semblance of continuity and visibility for the conversations that do happen, rather than conversations getting lost within a day or two as our site’s never ceasing hot question machine churns out HNQs.

Any objections?

Comment: Relevant: if anybody wants to follow the HNQ feed privately, the room uses the RSS feed found at https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/rpg.stackexchange.com and in general for more feeds or options see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314073

Answer (score 17):

Yes, let's switch it off. It fills entire page scrolls with chat messages in the room which impedes our ability to have conversations there now that things are slower. It can move to the ticker, but it should no longer be a main chat feed.

Comment: This seems to have attracted a solid consensus so I have disabled the HNQ feed.

Comment: Thank you @ObliviousSage

Comment: Much better like that, thank you!